# Why the array resulted from the stdin in Golang convert the last item to zero?

Tags: go

*Note: I am new to StackOverflow as well as to Programming, so if my question is not "so professional" or "well formatted", please forgive me.*

I am using the following Go (Golang) code to capture some space-separated numbers (string) from terminal, then split it into a slice. Later I'm converting this slice to a slice of float64 by getting one item at a time from the strings-slice and converting it to float64 and appending it to the float64-slice.
Then I'm returning the resulting float64 slice and printing it in the main function.
The problem is when I pass some space-separated digits to the terminal, the last digit is converted to zero.

for example if I pass `1 2 3 4 5` I expect the resulting slice as `[1 2 3 4 5]`, but it gives me the slice as `[1 2 3 4 0]`.

I'm trying from the last 5 hours, but I'm not able to find what I'm missing or messing.

code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    a := ReadInput()
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func ReadInput() []float64 {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    textSlice := strings.Split(text, " ")
    floatsSlice := make([]float64, 0)
    for _, elem := range textSlice {
        i, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(elem, 64)
        floatsSlice = append(floatsSlice, i)
    }

    return floatsSlice
}
```

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input,
>    returning a string containing the data up to and including the
>   delimiter.

so, `strings.Split(text, " ")` not splits last `\n` character so:
you may use `strings.Fields(text)` instead of  `strings.Split(text, " ")`
and always check for errors:
like this working sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    a := ReadInput()
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func ReadInput() []float64 {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    text, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    textSlice := strings.Fields(text)
    floatsSlice := make([]float64, 0)
    for _, elem := range textSlice {
        i, err := strconv.ParseFloat(elem, 64)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        floatsSlice = append(floatsSlice, i)
    }

    return floatsSlice
}
```